# How to output multiple user input values into a single variable in BATCH using Windows 7?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, input, output

### SOLVED!

**Update**: It figures moments after posting for help which is something I never do I'd figure it out...I tend to over think things, and that was the case here, it was just so simple! >.<

**Solution:**
(This worked under Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit)

```
Set var=
Set var=SomeText %var1% %var2% %var3%
Echo %var% > output.txt
```

See an explanation in my answer below.

---

I've been searching and trying several posts here similar to my question for hours with no success. I'm not new to Programming in BATCH but I have memory problems and thus can't always remember things. It also doesn't help that I program in other languages on other platforms which usually means I'm trying to use *nix shell commands in my Windows Batch scripts >.<

I've gotten quite close with some examples but nothing that works as needed.
Ideally, I'd like this work to work on Windows 7, 8, 8.1, Vista and 10 as that is the intended target.

**This is what I need to accomplish:**

The user will answer a series of questions, each question is stored into a .txt file (or variable if you prefer. I just used text files because of a past project where I ran into issues with variables that couldn't be solved and text files worked). The lines in each text file will need to be output into a single text file, on a single line which will then be read back in as a variable and run. Again, you could just use and combine the variables in your example if that's easier for you or both of us ;P

**This is a snippet example of how I was doing it**

```
    SET file1=
    SET /P file1=file1:%=%
    ECHO %file1% > file1.txt
```

**Then**

```
copy /b file1.txt + file2.txt + file3.txt + file4.txt output.txt
```

**Here is how I'd like the result to look**

```
toolkit /S "C:\ToolKit Bravo\Data\etc" "D:\ToolKit Bravo\Data\Ops"
```

The "" quotation marks are necessary. The output MUST be EXACTLY as shown above for the example I've given. The "/S" & paths are variable NOT fixed!

**Here is the best I've been able to come up with using variables..**

```
"toolkit /S "C:\ToolKit Bravo\Data\etc" "D:\ToolKit Bravo\Data\Ops""
```

**Update 2 - An explanation as requested:**

The paths in the above example directly above this are not fixed! This was an Example Only. "toolkit" is fixed, this doesn't change. "/S" is an option selected by the user to pass on to the "toolkit". Both the source and destination paths are again input by the user in "quotation" marks. They're not fixed paths.

As you can see the result is surrounded by quotations which is NOT acceptable. And Please remember, I NEED the quotations around the paths in the end result, so removing them all is NOT an option!

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: how did u get this result: "toolkit /S "C:\ToolKit Bravo\Data\etc" "D:\ToolKit Bravo\Data\Ops"" ?   Is this the text inside your output.txt file?

Comment: Yep, post more code, please, because currently the question is unclear.

Comment: I solved this, but I have updated the post to explain a little more for others in similar situations.

Comment: Yes, Amit dayama. This was the result in the output.txt file. It was caused by me thinking I needed to wrap the spaced variables in quotes when it wasn't needed. I've updated the post with the solution if you're curious.

Comment: You do not need to put the word **solved** in your question post; rather you should accept an answer (even your own) to mark a question as solved;

Comment: Hi aschipfl, You're right, I didn't have to put solved. However I wanted to make sure it was clear that it had been solved until I'm able to accept my own answer in 2 days time as the site allows. People don't always read everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

*This solved my problem under Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit*

```
Set var=
Set var=SomeText %var1% %var2% %var3%
Echo %var% > textfile.txt
```

Using the SET command I first made sure the variable or var for short was empty. Using this command:

```
    Set var=
```

I then proceeded to create my variable using all of the other variables I had created and wanted to combine using this line of code:

```
Set var=SomeText %var1% %var2% %var3%
```

Note that I have preceded the variables with "SomeText". This is where I'll place the name of the .exe I'm passing the arguments to, but it can be anything you want included. I also need spaces between each variable so I've left spaces between them in the example code. If you don't want the spaces simply remove them, and you'll have 1234, instead of 1 2 3 4.

Finally I send the combined variable out to a .txt file.

```
    Echo %var% > textfile.txt
```

However, you could also simply call the new variable now like this:

```
%var%
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take all of the characters between the quotes.

```
SET X="toolkit /S "C:\ToolKit Bravo\Data\etc" "D:\ToolKit Bravo\Data\Ops""
ECHO %X%
SET Y=%x:~1,-1%
ECHO %Y%
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the output wasn't fixed and changes based on the users input. I've updated the post to hopefully make this clearer.